# Is it required to have an API-Key to do trading with the 0x API (Swap/Quote)?

Tags: 0x

I am wondering if it's possible to use the 0x API Swap/Quote endpoint and further signing the transaction to the blockchain without an api-key for the API requests?

Are there any limitations if I do not have an API key?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No API key is needed to use our endpoints.

The API is intended for public use, so if you're just testing it out or building demo apps, it will cover those needs.

If you're an integrator who needs production-level rate limits, please fill out [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdUevfVTDbqnr2z7jBbuS-wMLu0wW9aHL0WZYb5B30TWFynhg/viewform) and our team will review and get back to you.

Comment: Hi Jess, thanks for your reply. Is access to the 0x Mesh (during a swap) the same with or without an API-Key?

Comment: Hi Vindberg - Mesh isn't really supported anymore (more details in this [README](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-mesh/blob/master/README.md)); however, in short, the swap endpoint does automatically aggregate liquidity across all our on-chain and off-chain sources. 

As a side note, we are actively working on updating the docs to reflect the mesh deprecation. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Hi again, does this mean that there is no 0x shared orderbook? Or does Matcha run their own? Is something else planned?

Comment: Hi Vindberg - Ah, I'll try to clarify with some historical context of what I understand.  

0x Mesh is not supported anymore, but 0x does have a shared orderbook which can be accesses through our [orderbook API](https://0x.org/docs/api#orderbook).

Comment: And if you see the term "relayers" floating around, that was mostly related to SRA, which stands for [Standard Relay API](https://github.com/0xProject/standard-relayer-api), was supported through v3 and has been replaced by /orderbook. The concept of a "relayer" still technically exists, but not in the same way that it was used in relation to Mesh.

Comment: Hi @0x_jess thanks for clarifying. When using the Quote api, will that include liquidity from the orderbook also or do I also need to call the orderbook endpoint to get swap prices from both?